# Не отображается Collection view cell

Tags: swift

Добавляю Collection view через Storyboard. Ставлю разные background'ы, но почему то сама ячейка не отображается. Кроме установки цветов и констрэинтов ничего не делал. Вот так это выглядит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не отображается сама ячейка?